# Qlikview EXCEL load row no from file

Tags: excel, row, qlikview

I have excel file with column, 
i need to laod in qlikview file row no from file to get in qlikview something like this

```
  rowNo1      Column1       Column2
   1           data1         data1
   2           data2         data2
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`load RowNo() as TheRowNo, Column1, Column2 from ...` will include the source file's row number to the table.

(Also see `RecNo()` in the documentation, it has a little different approach and you have to determine which suits your case best.)